# Converting Text to Image

Tags: image, text, imagemagick

I want to convert given text, say TEST, to image in different font and style.

I am using Imagemagick's convert command

```
convert -pointsize 120  -font Courier label:'TEST' test.png
```

But when I am using `-style` in the same, it is not changing into different style like Normal, Bold, Italic.

Please suggest how to get all 3 style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `-style` (e.g. `Italic`) and `-weight` (e.g. `Bold`) only work for certain fonts like postscript ones (unable to quote you a definitive source though).

What I use is fonts like `Courier-New-Bold`, `Courier-New-Italic`, `Courier-New-Bold-Italic`.
e.g.:

```
convert -pointsize 120 -font Courier label:'TEST' test.png
convert -pointsize 120 -font Courier-New-Bold label:'TEST' testbold.png
convert -pointsize 120 -font Courier-New-Italic label:'TEST' testitalic.png
convert -pointsize 120 -font Courier-New-Bold-Italic label:'TEST' testbolditalic.png
```

Most fonts have the `-Bold`, `-Italic`, and `-Bold-Italic` versions.
To see what fonts you can use, do `convert -list font` (or `convert -list type` if your ImageMagick is older). I do `convert -list font | grep Font:` to get a condensed list of just font names.