# How to create an image from font style

Tags: image, fonts, imagemagick, gimp

I need to create multiple images for each and every character of a specific font. For instance, I want to create separate images of size say 32x32 for all characters of english alphabet with Times New Roman, Arial, Sans, etc.

So I get 26 images for Times, 26 for Arial, 26 for Sans

Note: The character set I indent to create is of non-english language

Comment: If you search there are at least two posts asking a similar question over the last month and probably a lot more on this site. You do not say how you want to run the code bash - php - batch file etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convering Text to Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779931/convering-text-to-image)